# Scala strip trailing whitespace

Tags: scala, string

The Scala `String` method (in class `StringOps`) `stripMargin` removes leading whitespace from each line of a multi-line `String` up to and including the pipe (`|`) character (or other designated delimiter).

Is there an equivalent method to remove trailing whitespace from each line?

I did a quick look through the Scaladocs, but could not find one.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can easily use a regex for that:

```
input.replaceAll("""(?m)\s+$""", "")
```

The `(?m)` prefix in the regex makes it a multiline regex. `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespace characters and `$` the end of the line (because of the multiline flag).

Answer (score 30):

Java `String` method `trim` removes whitespace from beginning and end:

```
scala> println("<"+"  abc  ".trim+">")
<abc>
```

Comment: But that will only remove the whitespace from the first and lines lines, respectively, of a multi-line string.

Answer (score 7):

Split 'n' trim 'n' mkString (like a rock'n'roller):

```
val lines = """ 
This is 
 a test 
  a   foolish   
    test   
    a
test 
t 
 """

lines.split ("\n").map (_.trim).mkString ("\n")

res22: String = 

This is
a test
a   foolish
test
a
test
t
```

Comment: Note: split("\n") uses regex matching. Using split('\n') instead seems to convey intended meaning better (there will be no performance difference in recent world, as split is special casing for single character patterns anyway - see [Java split String performances](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11002374/16673).

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the most efficient way, but you could also do this:

```
val trimmed = str.lines map { s => s.reverse.dropWhile ( c => c == ' ').reverse.mkString(System.getProperty("line.seperator"))
```

Comment: nice `lines`, but `_ == ' '` is possible

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that after I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps: `s.lines.map(_.reverse.stripMargin.reverse).mkString("\n")` or with `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of `"\n"`?!

Answer (score -2):

```
str.reverse.dropWhile(_ == ' ').reverse
```