# Java split String performances

Tags: java, string, performance, optimization, split

Here is the current code in my application:

```
String[] ids = str.split("/");
```

When profiling the application, a non-negligeable time is spent string splitting. Also, the `split` method takes a regular expression, which is superfluous here.

What alternative can I use in order to optimize the string splitting? Is `StringUtils.split` faster?

(I would've tried and tested myself but profiling my application takes a lot of time.)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`String.split(String)` won't create regexp if your pattern is only one character long. When splitting by single character, it will use specialized code which is pretty efficient. `StringTokenizer` is not much faster in this particular case.

This was introduced in OpenJDK7/OracleJDK7. [Here's a bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6840246) and [a commit](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/rev/1ff977b938e5). I've made a [simple benchmark here](https://gist.github.com/2923321).

---

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)

$ java Split
split_banthar: 1231
split_tskuzzy: 1464
split_tskuzzy2: 1742
string.split: 1291
StringTokenizer: 1517
```

Comment: thanks for this benchmark. Your code is "unfair" though since the StringTokenizer part avoids creating a List and converting it to an array....great starting point though!

Comment: to avoid regex creation inside `split` method, having 1 char long pattern isn't enough. This char also must not be one of the regex meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\" e.g. `split(".")` will create/compile regex pattern. (verified on jdk8 at least)

Comment: In my version of Java 8 it does. From the split implementation comment: fastpath if the regex is a (1) one-char String and this character is not one of the RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter.

Comment: Adding a qualification. If you just put in say "|" that's going to be treated as regular expression. But "\\|" Is not treated as a regular expression. That confused me a bit at first.

Comment: At least the split_banthar (tested with copy/paste code) does NOT have the same behaviour has the JAVA SPLIT...

Answer (score 24):

If you can use third-party libraries, [Guava's](https://github.com/google/guava) [`Splitter`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) doesn't incur the overhead of regular expressions when you don't ask for it, and is very fast as a general rule.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

```
Iterable<String> split = Splitter.on('/').split(string);
```

(Also, `Splitter` is as a rule [much more predictable](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#splitter) than `String.split`.)

Comment: This made a very significant difference for me while using it on the lines from a large file.

Comment: This post recommends the non-use of Iterable even Guava's team lead says so...http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=2519

Comment: The blog entry has vanished but there is a [snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20150829130048/alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=2519) available in the internet archive.

Answer (score 9):

[`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) is much faster for simple parsing like this (I did some benchmarking with a while back and you get huge speedups).

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("1/2/3","/");
String[] arr = new String[st.countTokens()];
arr[0] = st.nextToken();
```

If you want to eek out a little more performance, you can do it manually as well:

```
String s = "1/2/3"
char[] c = s.toCharArray();
LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();
int index = 0;

for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++) {
    if(c[i] == '/') {
        ll.add(s.substring(index,i));
        index = i+1;
    }
}

String[] arr = ll.size();
Iterator<String> iter = ll.iterator();
index = 0;

for(index = 0; iter.hasNext(); index++)
    arr[index++] = iter.next();
```

Comment: StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Comment: Just because it's legacy doesn't mean it's not useful. And in fact, this particular class is actually very useful for that extra performance boost so I am actually against this "legacy" label.

Comment: The split method of `String` and the `java.util.regex` package incur the significant overhead of using regexes.  `StringTokenizer` does not.

Comment: @unknown Considering that the whole post is about the simple fact that `split` is horribly inefficient (it is, I had a simple parser that used split heavily and goodness apart from IO split dominated the whole thing) because of the additional complexities what exactly do you propose?

Comment: @tskuzzy it doesn't matter whether you are against "legacy" label or not, as javadoc says: its use discouraged.

Comment: how about using a regex ??

Comment: @NandkumarTekale  Why the dogmatic "legacy" discussion  If ST is much faster , it is much faster. Until the "recommended" code is equal or better in speed the label is potentially harmful.

Comment: @javadba : I would like you to go through [StringTokenizer javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). Search for "legacy" using `ctrl+f`

Comment: @NandkumarTekale   You did not apparently understand my point. But if you want to avoid using "legacy" classes in favor of "slow" ones that is your choice.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale. Tha reason why its called as legacy , is you cannot use stringtokenizer for splitting complex. ST just considers a delimiter and splits. Even if you repeat the delimiter n times. it would take them as just one. The only reason why its not deprecated is , there aint no serious security or memory flaw in it.  In papers, even deprecated code is discouraged but not blocked

Answer (score 8):

Seeing as I am working at large scale, I thought it would help to provide some more benchmarking, including a few of my own implementations (I split on spaces, but this should illustrate how long it takes in general):

I'm working with a 426 MB file, with 2622761 lines. The only whitespace are normal spaces (" ") and lines ("\n").

First I replace all lines with spaces, and benchmark parsing one huge line:

```
.split(" ")
Cumulative time: 31.431366952 seconds

.split("\s")
Cumulative time: 52.948729489 seconds

splitStringChArray()
Cumulative time: 38.721338004 seconds

splitStringChList()
Cumulative time: 12.716065893 seconds

splitStringCodes()
Cumulative time: 1 minutes, 21.349029036000005 seconds

splitStringCharCodes()
Cumulative time: 23.459840685 seconds

StringTokenizer
Cumulative time: 1 minutes, 11.501686094999997 seconds
```

Then I benchmark splitting line by line (meaning that the functions and loops are done many times, instead of all at once):

```
.split(" ")
Cumulative time: 3.809014174 seconds

.split("\s")
Cumulative time: 7.906730124 seconds

splitStringChArray()
Cumulative time: 4.06576739 seconds

splitStringChList()
Cumulative time: 2.857809996 seconds

Bonus: splitStringChList(), but creating a new StringBuilder every time (the average difference is actually more like .42 seconds):
Cumulative time: 3.82026621 seconds

splitStringCodes()
Cumulative time: 11.730249921 seconds

splitStringCharCodes()
Cumulative time: 6.995555826 seconds

StringTokenizer
Cumulative time: 4.500008172 seconds
```

Here is the code:

```
// Use a char array, and count the number of instances first.
public static String[] splitStringChArray(String str, StringBuilder sb) {
    char[] strArray = str.toCharArray();
    int count = 0;
    for (char c : strArray) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    String[] splitArray = new String[count+1];
    int i=0;
    for (char c : strArray) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            splitArray[i] = sb.toString();
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return splitArray;
}

// Use a char array but create an ArrayList, and don't count beforehand.
public static ArrayList<String> splitStringChList(String str, StringBuilder sb) {
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    words.ensureCapacity(str.length()/5);
    char[] strArray = str.toCharArray();
    int i=0;
    for (char c : strArray) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            words.add(sb.toString());
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return words;
}

// Using an iterator through code points and returning an ArrayList.
public static ArrayList<String> splitStringCodes(String str) {
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    words.ensureCapacity(str.length()/5);
    IntStream is = str.codePoints();
    OfInt it = is.iterator();
    int cp;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        cp = it.next();
        if (cp == 32) {
            words.add(sb.toString());
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        } else {
            sb.append(cp);
        }
    }

    return words;
}

// This one is for compatibility with supplementary or surrogate characters (by using Character.codePointAt())
public static ArrayList<String> splitStringCharCodes(String str, StringBuilder sb) {
    char[] strArray = str.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    words.ensureCapacity(str.length()/5);
    int cp;
    int len = strArray.length;
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        cp = Character.codePointAt(strArray, i);
        if (cp == ' ') {
            words.add(sb.toString());
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        } else {
            sb.append(cp);
        }
    }

    return words;
}
```

This is how I used StringTokenizer:

```
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(file.getCurrentString());
    words = new String[tokenizer.countTokens()];
    int i = 0;
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        words[i] = tokenizer.nextToken();
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: splitStringChList discards the last string.
Add  before return:
```java
if (sb.length() > 0) words.add(sb.toString());
```

Also:
- replace sb.delete(0, sb.length());  with sb.setLength(0);
- remove unused int i=0;

Comment: Also you should just make a string from a range in the char array rather than use a StringBuilder.

I don't find your implementation to be faster than split in java11

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.StringTokenizer(String str, String delim)` is about twice as fast according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/691224/1431971).

However, unless your application is of a gigantic scale, `split` should be fine for you (c.f. same post, it cites thousands of strings in a few miliseconds).

Comment: it doesn't take a gigantic-scale application, a split in a tight loop such as a document parser is enough -and frequent- Think about typical routines of parsing twitterlinks, emails, hashtags .... They are fed with Mb of text to parse. The routine itself can have a few dozen lines but will be called hundreds of times per second.

Answer (score 2):

Guava has a [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) which is more flexible that the `String.split()` method, and doesn't (necessarily) use a regex. OTOH, `String.split()` has been optimized in Java 7 to avoid the regex machinery if the separator is a single char. So the performance should be similar in Java 7.

Comment: Oh OK I'm using Java 5 (unfortunately yeah, can't change that)

Answer (score 1):

StringTokenizer is faster than any other splitting method, but getting the tokenizer to return the delimiters along with the tokenized string improves performance by something like 50%. That is achieved by using  the constructor `java.util.StringTokenizer.StringTokenizer(String str, String delim, boolean returnDelims)`. Here some other insights on that matter: [Performance of StringTokenizer class vs. split method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965767/performance-of-stringtokenizer-class-vs-split-method-in-java/18500975#18500975)

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache Commons Lang » 3.0 's

```
StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator("ab-!-cd-!-ef", "-!-") = ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
```

If you need non regex split and wants the results in String array, then use StringUtils, I compared StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator with Guava's Splitter and Java's String split, and found StringUtils is faster.

1. StringUtils - 8ms
2. String - 11ms
3. Splitter - 1ms (but returns Iterable/Iterator and converting them to string array takes total of 54ms)

Answer (score 0):

The String's split method is probably a safer choice. [As of at least java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) (though the api reference is for 7) they basically say that use of the StringTokenizer is discouraged. Their wording is quoted below.

"*StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.*"

Answer (score 0):

You can write the split function yourself , which is going to be the fastest.
Here is the link that proves it , it worked for me too, optimized my code by 6X

[StringTokenizer - reading lines with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356021/stringtokenizer-reading-lines-with-integers)

Split: 366ms
IndexOf: 50ms
StringTokenizer: 89ms
GuavaSplit: 109ms
IndexOf2 (some super optimised solution given in the above question): 14ms
CsvMapperSplit (mapping row by row): 326ms
CsvMapperSplit_DOC (building one doc and mapping all rows in one go): 177ms