# What is the fastest way to read/filter a text file

Tags: java

I'm trying to loop through a log text file, containing SSH logins and other logs.

The program is returning the total number of SSH logins.

My solution does work but seems a bit slow (~3.5 sec on a 200mo file). I would like to know if there are any ways to make it faster. I'm not really familiar with good practices on Java.

I'm using the `BufferedReader` class. Maybe there are better classes/methods but everything else I found online was slower.

```
{
            BufferedReader br;
            if(fileLocation != null) {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation));
            }
            else {
                br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8")));
            }
            String line;
            Stack<String> users = new Stack<>();
            int succeeded = 0;
            int failed;
            int total = 0;

            if(!br.ready()) {
                help("Cannot read the file", true);
            }
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                if(!line.contains("sshd")) continue;
                String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");
                if(arr.length < 11) continue;


                String log = arr[4];
                String log2 = arr[5];
                String log3 = arr[8];
                String user = arr[10];
                if(!log.contains("sshd")) continue;
                if(!log2.contains("Accepted")) {
                    if(log3.contains("failure")) {
                        total++;
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                total++;
                succeeded++;

                if(!repeat) {
                    if (users.contains(user)) continue;
                    users.add(user);
                }

                System.out.println((total + 1) + " " + user);
            }
```

Full code : https://pastebin.com/xp2P9wja

Also, here's some lines of the log file :

```
Dec  3 12:20:12 k332 sshd[25206]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.147.222.137 
Dec  3 12:20:14 k332 sshd[25204]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for illegal user admin from 10.147.222.137
Dec  3 12:20:14 k332 sshd[25204]: Failed keyboard-interactive/pam for invalid user admin from 10.147.222.137 port 36417 ssh2
Dec  3 12:20:14 k332 sshd[25204]: Connection closed by invalid user admin 10.147.222.137 port 36417 [preauth]
Dec  3 12:20:40 k332 sshd[25209]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): Tally overflowed for user root
```

Final output is :

```
Total :
103 unique IP SSH logins succeeded
30387 SSH logins succeeded
17186 SSH logins failed
47573 total SSH logins
```

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: Mo (Mega Octet) = MB (Mega Byte) (we usually say Mo in french)

Here's the full updated code is anyone needs it : https://pastebin.com/Kn5EqLNX

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "a 200mo file"?

Comment: Here are two hints to improve performance, AFAIK : `if` statements take time, you should **group** them using conditionnal operators (like `&&`). Printing in the console is also time consuming, you should remove the `System.out.println` that is in the `while` loop and wait for the end of the process, or at least only print every 100 or 1000 entries using a modulo `%`

Comment: Another way of optimising (and the *best* way) - `PasswordAuthentication no` in sshd_config ;)

Comment: I'm not an expert, but @g00se comment's sounds like a hacker phishing or a really bad joke

Comment: @gui3 *I'm not an expert* Well I'm inclined to believe you, but surely you could have a stab at guessing what `PasswordAuthentication no` *means* and whether it would tend toward hardening or softening security?

Comment: Jon Skeet : Sorry, i mean MB, not Mo.
gui3 : Ok thx i will try. For `System.out.println`, i already tried to remove it completly to test and improve the speed, but it doesn't do much. At least it improves time by ~0.1 sec, so that's still a win.
g00se : I cant, this is a exercice, we only have to create a Java program, not modify the ssh config. Thx tho, didn't know about this.

Comment: sorry to pollute this thread, but I need to mention to @g00se that **irony is hard to understand in written texts, furthermore when it's not your native language** (that's my case and the case of many users of SO) and if `PasswordAuthentication no` indeed means softening your security (with published IPs furthermore) I believe your comment could fool a lot of non-expert programmers. No offense though - but we're on SO to help or get helped, not to have fun IMO

Comment: @JonSkeet : 'Mo' means "megaoctet', an 'octet' being '8 bits'.

Comment: `Stack` is inefficient. Use `HashSet` instead. (Even though that's not where most of the CPU spends its time.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you get a profile of your code, it becomes clear that the problem is in the *String.split()* method:

[image]

This is a known problem in the standard Java library: [Java split String performances](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11002374/10390204).

So in order to speed up your code, you need to speed up this part of the code in some way. The first thing I can suggest is to replace the code on lines 75-79 with this:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!line.contains("sshd")) continue;
    String[] arr = pattern.split(line);
    if (arr.length < 11) continue;
...
}
```

This may speed up the code a bit, but you can see from the profile that a lot of time is still spent in Pattern and Matcher methods. We need to get rid of Pattern and Matcher for a significant speedup.

For single-character patterns split works without using Regex and does it quite efficiently, let's try replacing the code with:

```java
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!line.contains("sshd")) continue;
    String[] arr = Arrays.stream(line.split(" "))
                    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                    .toArray(String[]::new);
    if (arr.length < 11) continue;
...
}
```

This code runs almost twice as fast on the same data.

Comment: Nicee! It does lower the executation time per 2 thx a lot! i will now try to use a profile to better understand how to optimize my things